# How to convert many triangles to one mesh?

Tags: mesh

I wrote an algorithm to randomly generate terrain and I am trying to load and edit my results with blender.  The problem is that when I load my terrain in blender, the individual triangles are not linked together.

[image]

[image]
You can see when I shrink/flatten a subset the the faces, the rest don't follow and deform as a single mesh.

I tried deleting the faces and edges and using <kbd>F</kbd> to create faces from the points, but it does not give usable results.

[image]

How can I go about solving this problem?

Comment: How are you generating the terrain mesh? There is probably a way to get connected triangle from the get go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a mesh with many unconnected faces.
In edit mode select all the triangles with <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>. Then press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*. Or on the tool shelf <kbd>T</kbd> under the *Tools* tab press the *Remove Doubles* button.

Answer (score 4):

Select all triangles in *Object mode*, if the scene has no other objects <kbd>A</kbd>

- Join them to a single mesh <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>.
- Finally remove duplicated vertices.

In case the triangles are loose faces of a single object, removal of duplicate vertices should do the job.

[image]

Comment: When I do this I get an error, "No mesh data to join." And it seams it's already a single object in object mode.  But still in edit mode, the triangles are not linked together.

Comment: Try skipping the first bullet, and head straight to the second

Comment: @stacker Don't think the objects are separate, just the faces.